# cookies are not set if you send request from different domain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

- Sanctum Version: 2.11.2
- Laravel Version: 8.55.0
- PHP Version: 7.4.20
- *Laravel is running on: http://127.0.0.1:8000*
- *front end (vue) is running on: http://localhost:3000*

I put all following in my .env file

```
COOKIE_SAME_SITE_POLICY=strict
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
SESSION_DOMAIN='.127.0.0.1'
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS='.localhost,.localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1'
```

When I'm trying to authenticate from a different domain it gives 419 error CSRF token mismatch, the first request "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie" which must set the cookies does not set anything however if I try the same request inside laravel instance it sets the cookies and works as expected

how every the same request sets the cookies successfully in postman

Steps To Reproduce:

1. install laravel "composer create-project laravel/laravel sanctum"
2. change `'supports_credentials' => false,` to `'supports_credentials' => true,` from **/config/cors.php**
3. set up the vue app on "http://localhost:3000" and send a request to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie" and it will not set the cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set a cookie for a different domain for security reasons

Comment: then why did they set ** SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS** isn't it for receiving requests from other domains (origin)s